# Tower of Hanoi recursion java

Tags: java, recursion

Here's my Java code for solving Tower of Hanoi using recursion:

```
/**here is a stack of N disks on the first of three poles (call
them A, B and C) and your job is to move the disks from pole A to pole B without
ever putting a larger disk on top of a smaller disk.*/ 

public class Hanoi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playHanoi (2,"A","B","C");
    }

    //move n disks from position "from" to "to" via "other"
    private static void playHanoi(int n, String from , String other, String to) {
        if (n == 0)
            return;
        if (n > 0)
        playHanoi(n-1, from, to, other);
        System.out.printf("Move one disk from pole %s to pole %s \n ", from, to);
        playHanoi(n-1, other, from, to);
    }

}
```

Does the place I put the print method matter? Also, can I do it like this:

```
    playHanoi(n-1, from, to, other);
    playHanoi(n-1, other, from, to);
    System.out.printf("Move one disk from pole %s to pole %s \n ", from, to);
```

Comment: yes it does.....the `printf` in 1st case will be between the function calls, and in the latter, after the two function calls.

Comment: run it pls and see the output to understand the difference....

Comment: also, 1st method is better (and correct), since you should not move the disks using your second approach....think why :)

Comment: The beautiful thing about code is you can just try running it and see what happens.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solving `Tower of Hanoy` problem in this way, is nothing but defining the strategy of how you want to get the job done. And your code :

```
    playHanoi(n-1, from, to, other);
    System.out.printf("Move one disk from pole %s to pole %s \n ", from, to);
    playHanoi(n-1, other, from, to);
```

Basically defines your strategy to like bellow,

1. Move ***n-1*** disks from ***"from"*** (source tower) to ***"other"*** (intermediary tower).
2. Then move ***n*** th disk from ***"from"*** (source tower) to ***"to"*** (destination tower).
3. Finally move ***n-1*** disks from ***"other"*** (intermediary tower) to ***"to"*** (destination tower).

Your `prinf` basically does the ***2*** nd step.

Now if you write code like this:

```
    playHanoi(n-1, from, to, other);
    playHanoi(n-1, other, from, to);
    System.out.printf("Move one disk from pole %s to pole %s \n ", from, to);
```

Then you are basically doing:

1. Move ***n-1*** disks from ***"from"*** (source tower) to ***"other"*** (intermediary tower).
2. Then move ***n-1*** disks from ***"other"*** (intermediary tower) to ***"to"*** (destination tower).
3. Finally move ***n*** th disk from ***"from"*** (source tower) to ***"to"*** (destination tower).

   > In this strategy, after doing the ***2*** nd step (moving all  ***n-1*** disks from ***"other"*** to ***"to"***), *3* rd step becomes invalid(moving ***n*** th disk from ***"from"*** to ***"to"***)! Because in `Tower of Hanoy` you cant put a larger disk on a smaller one!

So choosing the second option(strategy) leads you to an invalid strategy, thats why you can not do that!

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed matter.  Anything after your recursion call will be executed after that recursion unwinds (and anything before it, before), so you might find your output is in a nonsensical order.

Keep in mind that the statement after the function call doesn't execute until the function returns.